# Voting hover text on meta is misinformative

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta

As I understand, voting on the meta is supposed to be fundamentally different than voting on the main. By this I mean on the Main:

- Upvotes mean: well researched, clear etc.
- Downvotes mean: badly researched, unclear etc.

On the Meta:

- Upvotes: I agree
- Downvotes: I disagree

So why is it that when I hover over the up and down vote buttons on a post in the meta it shows the same hover text as on the main?

This could be misinformative to users who may be unaware on how meta voting works.

So changing the hover text to "I agree with this answer/question/whatever" and "I disagree with this answer/question/whatever" may help distinguish clearly the functionality of voting on the meta.

---

This may be applicable to other metas as well so this question may possibly need to be migrated to the SE meta.

Comment: By the way, this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear. +1.

Comment: [Related, declined, feature request on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites).

Comment: @DanielR Do you know why exactly it was declined?

Comment: Jeff Atwood seems to have been against it, as his heavily downvoted answer suggests. This could have something to do with it. But it's only speculation, I haven't seen the post before. I agree with your suggestion fwiw (+1).

Comment: BTW: The original intent for the agree/disagree voting system was limited to [feature-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) questions only. While we (and some other sites) do extend the same scheme to most questions on meta, I don't know if that is in fact universally true.